# jQuery Flot: change line color at threshold / coordinate

Tags: javascript, flot, threshold

I'm wondering if it's possible in Flot to change a line's colour when it goes above/below a threshold. A smooth transition / gradient would be preferable, but if it has to be abrupt, I think I could live with that.

Here's a quick-n-dirty example of how I'd like the graph to look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get smooth transitions, but you can get abrupt ones using the [thresholding plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/threshold/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that. I was thinking it would be some property to be set in the init object.